# Find intersections and differences between two 2d arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, difference, intersect

I have two arrays.

```
$paternalSiblings = fname => John lname => Doe gender => M birth_year => 1988
                    fname => Sophie lname => Ellison gender => F birth_year => 1990

$maternalSiblings = fname => John lname => Smith gender => M birth_year => 1997    
                    fname => John lname => Doe gender => M birth_year => 1988
```

Output of the arrays:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [fname] => John [lname] => Doe [birth_year] => 1988[gender] => Male [fname] => Sophie [lname] => Ellison [birth_year] => 1990 [death_date] => [gender] => Female ) ) 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [fname] => John [lname] => Doe [birth_year] => 1988[gender] => Male [fname] => John [lname] => Smith [birth_year] => 1997 [death_date] => [gender] => Male ) ) 

$fullSiblings = $this->arrayIntersect( $paternalSiblings , $maternalSiblings );

<?php
function arrayIntersect( $primary_array, $secondary_array ) {

     if ( !is_array( $primary_array ) || !is_array( $secondary_array ) ) {
         return false;
     }

     if ( !empty( $primary_array ) ) {

         foreach( $primary_array as $key => $value ) {

             if ( !isset( $secondary_array[$key] ) ) {
                 unset( $primary_array[$key] );
             } else {
                 if ( serialize( $secondary_array[$key] ) != serialize( $value ) ) {
                     unset( $primary_array[$key] );
                 }
             }

         }

         return $primary_array;

     } else {
         return array();
     }

     } 
    ?>
```

This function doesn't work. How could I intersect and differ the arrays? I noticed that built-in functions array_intersect_assoc() and array_diff_assoc() don't work with multidimensional arrays. What's the best way to achieve the goal?

Comment: Can you post the `print_r()` output of both the arrays and post what you've tried so far?

Comment: These are matrices are this point. This looks like a job for linear algebra!http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/189285/calculate-intersection-of-vector-subspace-by-using-gauss-algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need at least a **fixed value** to identify each row, and check differences for others values.

```
$first = array(
 "uniqueId1" => array("name" => "Ignacio", "email" => "user@server.com"),
 "uniqueId2" => array("name" => "John", "email" => "jh@server.com")
);

$second = array(
 "uniqueId1" => array("name" => "Ignacio", "email" => "other@server.com"),
 "uniqueId2" => array("name" => "Luis", "email" => "jh@server.com")
);
```

And you cand compare and get differences with:

```
foreach($first as $keyRow => $firstRow) {
 if(isset($second[$keyRow])) { //The first row exists in second array, so, I will check it
  foreach($firstRow as $key => $value) {
   if($second[$keyRow][$key] != $value) {
    echo "For row: ".$keyRow.", ".$second[$keyRow][$key]." is not equal to: ".$value."<br />";
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Output:

```
For row: uniqueId1, other@server.com is't equal to: user@server.com
For row: uniqueId2, Luis is't equal to: John
```

Answer (score 0):

- Find the rows in `$paternalSiblings` which are wholly different from rows in `$maternalSiblings`:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_udiff($paternalSiblings, $maternalSiblings, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
  );
  ```
- Find the rows in `$maternalSiblings` which are wholly different from rows in `$paternalSiblings`:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_udiff($maternalSiblings, $paternalSiblings, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
  );
  ```

---

- Find the rows in `$paternalSiblings` which are wholly identical to rows in `$maternalSiblings`:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_uintersect($paternalSiblings, $maternalSiblings, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
  );
  ```
- Find the rows in `$maternalSiblings` which are wholly identical to rows in `$paternalSiblings`:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_uintersect($maternalSiblings, $paternalSiblings, fn($a, $b) => $a <=> $b)
  );
  ```

---

- Find the associative elements in `$paternalSiblings` which are different from elements in `$maternalSiblings` by comparing rows with the same first level position:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_map('array_diff_assoc', $paternalSiblings, $maternalSiblings)
  );
  ```
- Find the associative elements in `$maternalSiblings` which are different from elements in `$paternalSiblings` by comparing rows with the same first level position:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_map('array_diff_assoc', $maternalSiblings, $paternalSiblings)
  );
  ```

---

- Find the associative elements in `$paternalSiblings` which are identical to elements in `$maternalSiblings` by comparing rows with the same first level position:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_map('array_intersect_assoc', $paternalSiblings, $maternalSiblings)
  );
  ```
- Find the associative elements in `$maternalSiblings` which are identical to elements in `$paternalSiblings` by comparing rows with the same first level position:

  ```
  var_export(
      array_map('array_intersect_assoc', $maternalSiblings, $paternalSiblings)
  );
  ```