# compare two collection arrays in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I'm working with `laravel`, and I have two collection arrays that look something like this:

```
$collection1 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'phone', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3, 'price' => 800],
];

$collection2 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'phone', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3, 'price' => 400],
];
```

so I need to know if they are the same or not, comparing both collections. and if in some of the arrays one of the keys (or several) has a different value, then they will no longer be the same collections, for example in 1 collection the price of the second item has a value of 800 and the other collection of 400. there is Any native method of laravel collections to do this ?, or how can i do it with simple php arrays?

Comment: Did you tried with [array_diff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php) ?

Comment: `array_diff()` does not work with 2d arrays.  If you are comfortable converting collections to arrays, then see some relevant tools at: [Find intersections and differences between two 2d arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78190104/2943403)

Answer (score 8):

the laravel collections have a method called diff, with this method you can Get the items in the collection that are not present in the given items. and the items is $collection2 which can be an array or a collection so you can take the different items between this two collection like this

```
$collection1->diff($collection2);
```

it returns a Illuminate\Support\Enumerable class.
you can get the items by call all() on this:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

$differentItems = $collection->diff([2, 4, 6, 8]);

$differentItems->all();

// [1, 3, 5]
```

this code belongs to laravel docs. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-diff .
and at the end you can turn $differentItems to boolean. like this:

```
$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$differentItems = $collection->diff([2, 4, 6, 8]);
$differentItems->isEmpty();
// return false

$collection = collect([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
$differentItems = $collection->diff($collection);
$differentItems->isEmpty();
// return true
```

more links https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_diff https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Support/Enumerable.html

Comment: This clearly doesn't work because the elements inside the collections are array.

Comment: @AliKhalili then turn the arrays to collections and check e.g.
 `collect($collection1)->diff(collect($collection2))->isEmpty();`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. You may want to take a look at [answer].

Comment: This only works if the first collection has elements that the second collection does not. If the second collection has additional elements, then those will not show up in the diff. If you want to truly tell if the collections are identical, then you need to do the diff in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

So serialize each element first, and then compare.

```php
    $serialize1 = $collection1->map(function ($item) {
        return serialize($item);
    });

    $serialize2 = $collection2->map(function ($item) {
        return serialize($item);
    });

dd($serialize1->diff($serialize2)->isEmpty());
```

Comment: serialization is not the proper way of comparing arrays. changing the order of items in a key/value array changes the serialized result where as logically, it doesn't affect the array equality.

Answer (score 0):

Follows a comparison function:

```php
function compareCollections($c1, $c2) {
    // If the colletions have different sizes we return false:
    if (count($c1) != count($c2)) {
        return false;
    }

    // The collections have the same size, we check element by element:
    foreach($c1 as $item) {

        // We find the current element in $c1 in $c2:
        $itemToCompare = array_filter($c2, function ($compareItem) use ($item) {
            return ($compareItem['id'] == $item['id']);
        });

        // If we did not find the element in $c2, the collections are different:
        if (empty($itemToCompare)) {
            return false;
        }

        $itemToCompare = current($itemToCompare);

        // We now use PHP to check the element keys:
        $diff = array_diff_key($item, $itemToCompare);

        // If there is a different, return false:
        if (!empty($diff)) {
            return false;
        }       
    }

    // If everything is ok until here, the collections are the same:
    return true;
}
```

And a test:

```php
$collection1 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'phone', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3, 'price' => 800],
];

$collection2 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'phone', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3, 'price' => 400],
];

$collection3 = [
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3],
];

var_dump(compareCollections($collection1, $collection2)); // true
var_dump(compareCollections($collection1, $collection3)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, as your collection items are array, there is no native simple Laravel way to do so and you should write a function to compare them:

So, assuming that, you have:

```
$collection1 = collectt([
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'phone', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3, 'price' => 800],
]);

$collection2 = collect([
    ['id' => 1, 'name'=> 'phone', 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => 1200],
    ['id' => 2, 'name'=> 'tv', 'quantity' => 3, 'price' => 400],
]);
```

You can for example compare them by:

```
    private function collectionsAreEqual($collection1, $collection2)
    {
        if ($collection1->count() != $collection2->count()) {
            return false;
        }
        //assuming that, from each id, you don't have more that one item:
        $collection2 = $collection2->keyBy('id');
        foreach ($collection1->keyBy('id') as $id => $item) {
            if (!isset($collection2[$id])) {
                return false;
            }
            //your items in the collection are key value arrays 
            // and can compare them with == operator
            if ($collection2[$id] != $item) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    dd(collectionsAreEqual($collection1, $collection2));
```

Answer (score 0):

This method only works if both collections have the same key order.

By default, Laravel has a diffAssoc method which actually compares the single item of a collection. If you want to compare two collection arrays then you have to create your own solution.

Here is my solution where I create(or you can say extend) a collection method.

First I map each item and serialize the item and then do the same with another collection. Get the difference by using the diffAssoc method and unserialize the final output.

***AppServiceProvider.php***

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Collection::macro('diffAssocMultiple', function ($anotherCollection) {
            /* @var $this Collection */
            return $this->map(function($arr) {
                return serialize($arr);
            })->diffAssoc($anotherCollection->map(function($arr) {
                return serialize($arr);
            }))->map(function($arr) {
                return unserialize($arr);
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Usage

```
$diff = $collectionOne->diffAssocMultiple($collectionTwo);
```

Note that, this new method returns another collection(non-zero based). and this doesn't have the 'all()' method as diffAssoc has.
If you want a zero-based index array then use the values function along with.

```
$diff = $collectionOne->diffAssocMultiple($collectionTwo)->values();
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up comparing simply the output of `toJson()` of collections. I can't say how bad this is in terms of performance, but it's fine for my case (unit tests).